# The entity framework provider could not be loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have the following config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.93.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="catalogoSQLiteADO" connectionString="Data Source=D:\Alvaro\proyectos\Catalogo\RepositorioBaseDatosBase\catalogo.sqlite3;foreign keys=True;" />
    <add name="catalogoEntitiesSQLiteEF5" connectionString="metadata=res://*/catalogoSQLiteEF5.csdl|res://*/catalogoSQLiteEF5.ssdl|res://*/catalogoSQLiteEF5.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=D:\Alvaro\proyectos\catalogo\RepositorioBaseDatosBase\catalogo.sqlite3&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.93.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I would like to use EF6 with SQLite, but when I try to execute the application I get the following error:

```
The entity framework provider type 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProiderServices, System.Datal.SQLite.EF, Cesion=1.0.93.0, CUlture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and the assembly is available to the running application.
```

I have the references to the dlls in the project.

Thanks.

Comment: You have the correct version of SQLite installed from Nuget?

Comment: Yes, I have uninstalled and installed the nuget packge of SQLite, that isntalls SQLite dlls and the EF6, version 6.1.1. This update the config file, but it does not work.

Comment: As @DavidG I would guess SQLite-version, but barring that, I see that you have a connection string with EF5 in it, are you sure that you might not have version issues with EF? Have you tried to create a new dummy project and see what happens?

Comment: Oh, yes, in the connection string is EF5 but because I am doing tries and I forget to change the name.

Comment: Did you check the bin folder of your exe just to make sure the dll is in there?

Comment: I've just run into the same thing. I'm using EF6 and System.Data.SQLite.EF6 v 1.0.94. Apparently the System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices is "internal" and inaccessible from the outside... should it be that way?